# gwt java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: exception, gwt, initialization, rpc

I'm working on a GWT app, and keep getting the error shown below.

I followed the GWT tutorial regarding naming conventions for servlet classes, and followed the Service / Async / ServiceImpl structure.

I also tried adding the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` VM argument to fix a previous problem. any ideas on what's going on?

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC    
call
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at   

com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_   
(Runtime.java:127)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance  
(Runtime.java:135)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.instantiate 
(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:914)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize 
(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:556)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject 
(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
at   
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8. 
readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:138)
at  
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue 
(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:303)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall  
(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost  
(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost
(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter
(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter
(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter
(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter
(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter
(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle
(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle
(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at  
com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle
(JettyContainerService.java:369)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable    
in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are  
running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that 
GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.<clinit>(UIObject.java:187)
... 46 more
```

Comment: noticed the `ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable    
in client code!`? look it up in your servlets

Comment: i don't have GWT.create() in my server code, only in client code

Comment: did you configure you deployment descriptor (`web.xml`) accordingly?

Comment: yes, put the Impl class name for servlet name and put the import for the servlet class name. and in servlet mapping, did the same thing for the servlet name, and put the gwt.xml rename-to attribute and the RemoteServiceRelativePath("thisthing") in the url pattern starting with a / and deparated by a /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost for sure you are calling a class that is GWT client only. You have the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable    
in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are  
running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that 
GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
```

You don't need to specifically call "GWT.create()" yourself to get that exception. you might be calling a GWT client only class on the server side. Also you might containg a "client only" object in one of your RPC's arguments or even on shared code being called on the server side.

Comment: the class i have as an argument and that im trying to return from server side is a class defined on client side. but i imported it on the server side class.

Comment: That can actually be the problem. Even if that class is implemented and instantiated on the client code, it'll still throw an error when used on server side (if it's created using GWT.create()). Try changing that argument into a String for example (just to see if the error dissapears), and see if it works. If the error dissapears, than you'll be sure it's beacuse you're using that class. And you'll need a mechanism to avoid its usage on server side.

Comment: i tried making the argument AND the return type to a string and that didnt. these are the objects used to do the whole call thing: private GridServiceAsync gridSvc = GWT.create(GridService.class); and AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() with the definition. if i put GridServiceImpl.class in the GWT.create() along with the argument and return type changes i get this error: No source code is available for type com.test.grid.button.server.GridServiceImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module? GridServiceImpl is the class on serverside

Comment: oh snap, i restarted eclipse and i tried it with just GWT.create(GridService.class); and it worked. the class argument and return type really was the problem...

Comment: i guess ill see how to change the implementation so it will work. thanks a lot for your help Nuno

Comment: ok so previously the class i was trying to use as an argument and return type extended Grid, but now i just have a Grid as an instance variable and now im getting these errors:    [ERROR] [gridbuttons] - com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid is not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' or 'java.io.Serializable' nor does it have a custom field serializer (reached via com.test.grid.button.client.TheGrid). So im guessing Grid is simply not Serializable? If thats the case thats a total bummer cuz thats pretty much all my app is..

Comment: Why do you want to pass a Grid from/to the server? That doesn't make sense. Just pass the information you want to fill the Grid with. It's the correct approach. Just create a serializable object (implements java.io.Serializable or gwt.IsSerializable) and fill it with the data you have on the grid (or vice versa, send that info from the server and fill the grid with it). There's no point in sending widgets to the server. If my response helped you, please tick it as accepted.

Comment: if i do it that way, then more work gets done than is needed. but at this point i just want this thing to work through RPC. maybe im missing something about RPC, what exactly are its benefits?

Comment: Well, of the top of my head... communicate with the server to get data from there not to overload the client code with all data the application needs to run. That's why it doesn't make sense to pass widgets back and forth. You pass data and fill the widgets with the objects from server, and vice versa. I suggest you read this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the same error and it ended up being a constant (static final) that used GWT.create() to initialise.  The constant was in a class that needed to be loaded by the GIN dependency injection parser.

IE: It was trying to load the class (and call GWT.create()) during module compile.